# Why Doesn't LinkedIn Give Me the Option to Publish a Post for Job Seeking?

Tags: linkedin

I've updated my status to 'Open to Work', but LinkedIn isn't providing me with the box that's typically used to notify my network that I'm looking for a job. What steps can I take to rectify this? I want to make a post similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: Please review [LinkedIn: Let recruiters know you’re Open to Work](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a507508/let-recruiters-know-you-re-open-to-work) then [edit] your question to confirm the specific steps you took to enable the **#OpenToWork feature** from your LinkedIn profile and at what point they failed.